# how to batch change the field of the table in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

In lua, now I want to change field name of a table, like

in test1.lua

```
local t = {
player_id = 2,
item_id = 1,
}
return t
```

in test2.lua

```
local t = require "test1"
print( t.item_id )
```

if I want to change field name `item_id` -> `item_count` of `t`,

I need to use the application like `ultraedit`, find out all lua file contain `item_id`, and modified one by one, such modification easy correction or change of leakage, is there any tools can be more easily modified the field name?

Comment: This could be done with an UltraEdit script. But your task description is not detailed enough to write the few lines of script code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly:

(What if item_id also happens to be a field in a different table?)

In my view, there is no generic solution for this task without actually interpreting the script.  A field name (e.g., item_id) could appear in many places but be referring to different tables.  To make sure you change only references to the correct table you need to actually interpret the script.  Given the dynamic nature of Lua scripts, this is not a trivial task.

Using an editor (or preferably a Lua script) to globally replace all occurrences of one name to another will only work if you're certain the 'old' name has only a single context.

A run-time workaround might be to add some metatable to keep both the new and the old name.  I think you need to play with the __index and __newindex  events.  Then, the same field will be accessed by either 'old' or 'new' name.

Example for the metatable trick (only field 'one' is actually part of the table, field 'two' access is made possible via the metatable to read/write field 'one' so that reading from 'two' reads 'one', while writing to 'two' writes to 'one'):

```
t = {}

t.one = 1

setmetatable(t,{__index = function(t,k)
                            if k == 'two' then return t.one end
                          end,
                __newindex = function(t,k,v)
                               if k == 'two' then t.one = v end
                             end
               })

print(t.one,t.two)
t.two = 2
print(t.one,t.two)
```